# jquery check if a option is selected

Tags: jquery, select

```
$('#arrow-left').click(function() {

    var sel = $('#right option:selected').val();

    $('#left').append('<option value="'+sel+'">'+ sel +'</option>');

});
```

The above is my code. I append an option from a `selectbox #right` into a `selectbox #left` upon click. However, I need to make sure that an option is selected in the `#right` or I get "undefined" options in the `#left` select form.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check whether a selected option exists

```
$('#arrow-left').click(function () {
    var $selected = $('#right option:selected');
    if ($selected.length) {
        var sel = $selected.val();
        $('#left').append('<option value="' + sel + '">' + sel + '</option>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, with `$('#right').val()` you'd be getting the current value of the select, no matter if user-selected or default.

```
$('#arrow-left').click(function() {
    var sel = $('#right').val();
    $('#left').append('<option value="'+sel+'">'+ sel +'</option>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/KsQUX/

```
var $sel1 = $('select:first'),
    $sel2 = $('select:last');


$sel1.change(function(){
    var $op = $(this).find('option:selected');
    $sel2.append($op);
});
```